# How do USS Enterprise Crew members receive emails or other forms of personal messages?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-eu

Let's say that I am a human living in the Star Trek universe, during the time that any Starship Enterprise exists. I want to send Captain Kirk a letter. How would I address it so that it ought get to him?

Comment: I'm confused. Are you asking from an in-universe perspective, like "if I were a human on Earth in the *Star Trek* universe, how would I send mail to the Enterprise?"; or are you asking if the Enterprise has a real mailing address (like [Santa](https://www.canadapost.ca/web/en/blogs/announcements/details.page?article=2015/11/19/time_to_write_to_san&cattype=announcements&cat=newsreleases)), or are you asking something else entirely?

Comment: In the show, and as an in-universe perspective.

Comment: chances are, it'd work like email - but possibly screened by StarFleet spam filters

Comment: I don't see how it would be any different from today - you'd send it to the person's account and the ship would connect the Starfleet mail servers and download all new messages to everyones inbox - exactly like it would work with any offline device/location now.

Comment: @Jocie - Except that isn't what we see. They seem to get "message packets" containing all sorts of chaff like magazine subscriptions, low-level orders, personal letters, etc etc all in one single data-dump.

Comment: @Valorum How is that any different to connecting your phone to the Internet after having been offline for 2-3 days? Everything comes in one bulk update. I would guess the Enterprise connects, lets everything sync, and then disconnects once it's done (to save on roaming fees).

Comment: How to correctly address mails is something that's really hard to get information about, sadly.  You can try to check sites like http://www.columbia.edu/~fdc/postal/ ; or dig for information in the particular national postal service company that handles that region, but that information is often scattered and well hidden and available only in one language.

Comment: "computer, send the following to captain Kirk of the uss enterprise: blah blah..." ... The rest is just details nobody needs to know

Comment: @Jocie - As discussed in a previous answer, messages in Star Trek seem to be destructive. When you copy them, the previous version  gets destroyed.

Comment: @PlasmaHH: The guy programming the computer needs to know.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: given how they "program" holodeck stuff, I am not sure if the general ships AI doesn't account for that already...

Comment: @PlasmaHH: Somebody has to create the AI - it doesn't materialise out of thin air!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: On Star Trek, once enough data has accumulated, there's a certain chance for AIs to suddenly emerge if you don't watch your equipment closely. Even more likely if the device in question has at least one anthropomorphic feature. Has happened more than once ;)

Comment: Kirk doesnt have time for 'mail' - too busy fighting, saving the universe and kissing aliens (or yeomans). He does this in every episode. Not even sure he has time for sleep, let alone mail.

Comment: Captain.  Jean-Luc Picard. Of the USS En-ter-prise.  Captain.  Jean-Luc Picard. Of the USS En-ter-prise.  Now that Pogo video is stuck in my head.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Given that the location of the USS Enterprise seems to be at least *slightly* classified (and when they're on fleet maneuvers, *very* classified), you'd probably need to send your letter in electronic form to Starfleet Headquarters to be forwarded onward the next time the ship makes contact and downloads a message bundle. We see several examples of this in the various Trek shows.

**Enterprise**

> **ARCHER:** *What's the word from home?*
>
> **TUCKER:** *The usual, engineering updates. Oh, and Duvall got promoted. They're giving him the Shenandoah.*
>
> **ARCHER:** *Duvall got his own command? Thank God we're a hundred light years away.*
>
> **TUCKER:** *And **I got a letter** from Natalie.*
>
> <sub><sup>[ENT: Silent Enemy](http://www.chakoteya.net/Enterprise/12.htm)</sup></sub>

**TNG**

> **COMM VOICE:** *Bridge to Captain Picard.*
>
> **PICARD:** *Picard here.*
>
> **COMM VOICE:** ***There's a personal message for you** from Earth.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Star Trek: Generations](http://www.chakoteya.net/movies/movie7.html)</sup></sub>

Comment: That sounds reasonable! Is there any mention of Starfleet Headquarters' address, and/or a reasonable extrapolation from real-life analogues?

Comment: @Lolologist: I believe it’s in San Francisco, and that we see it during, for example, Voyager’s *[Non Sequitur](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Non_Sequitur_(episode))*, and Deep Space Nine’s *[Homefront](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Homefront_(episode))*.

Comment: Since "letters" in the future are simply emails or video-messages, I'd imagine that each person would have their own dedicated email address. Failing that, you could just send them to **Captain Kirk, Starship Enterprise, c/o Starfleet HQ, San Francisco** and they'd probably get to him (eventually).

Comment: Kirk is pretty famous. I would imagine he has a mail service that deals with his fan-mail.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite The movies, notably *The Voyage Home*, also show that Starfleet Headquarters are in San Francisco.

Comment: "Given that ..." - in other words, exactly like today? You can send me a message (e-mail to an e-mail address, text message to a phone number, to some extent (at least on a town-scope) even physical letters to a P.O.Box or to some special entities) without having to know where I am, because a trusted party is our mutual point of contact?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper - I suspect it may be rather more complicated when  dealing with an interstellar network. And much more akin to the "mail ships" of the Navy where a *single copy* is shunted around until it reaches its destination.

Comment: @Valorum: "I suspect it may be rather more complicated when dealing with an interstellar network." - why would that be?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper - It could be a bit like bitcoin, where the message propogates outwards to the entire network, then gets deleted when a node detects that the relevant bit (in this case a letter) has reached its destination but what we tend to see are "message packets" where multiple messages including engineering updates, low-level orders, etc are all bundled together.

Comment: @Valorum: Yes, it *might* be like that, but why? I really don't see a reason why it would be any more complicated with today's communication systems. Or, put differently: Based upon what we can find in canon material, *nothing* seems to point to sending messages to someone on a starship being any more difficult than establishing remote communication today. Also, note that you're describing how it works technically, but that still doesn't change anything about how users specify a destination address.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper - I already addressed that. You write "Cap'n Kirk, care of Starfleet" on the letter and it'll get there.

Comment: @Valorum: Mhm. So, that seems to confirm [my earlier comment](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/145313/if-i-wanted-to-send-mail-to-the-uss-enterprise-how-would-i-address-it/145315?noredirect=1#comment370909_145315) that it's "exactly like today".

Comment: I suspect that the idea of sending letters in paper form is a little bit alien to them. So the word "letter" probably means "email" or some analogue.

Comment: @PointlessSpike - Jake Sisko writes on real paper. It's seen as a bit weird and retro.

Comment: @Valorum- To be fair to them, I always have the same reaction when I see some of the older people at work doing that.

Comment: @PointlessSpike - Someone gave me a *handwritten* CV a few weeks ago. Very odd.

Comment: It's interesting the to/from of messages doesn't seem to have been addressed (excuse the pun) but wonder if they have an email like address e.g. james.t.kirk@enterprise.uss but is a good question!

Comment: @RoguePlanetoid: Although that could be a bit impractical for people who often change assignments. Also, down to what level should that be resolved? Single runabouts count as ships in their own right, too. Not to mention possible classified assignments ... no, it would seem like a better design not to mention a ship or station name in the "e-mail address" to Starfleet personnel.

Answer (score 8):

In the instances where someone aboard the Enterprise *sent* a message to someone else, they did not seem to use anything like an email address. Rather they would simply say to the computer "Prepare a message for Admiral Nechayev at Star Fleet Command" From that, I believe it can be construed that the computer is expected to locate the correct person, or to notify the sender if the recipient cannot be identified.  The most likely mechanism would be for the computer to work backwards, starting with "Star Fleet Command" and then either interrogating a database at command to locate Admiral Nechayev, or simply sending the message to command and expecting that further routing would be handled behind the scenes, so to speak. The underlying mechanisms might not be all that different than what we use now, simply made more user friendly and intelligent.

Comment: Can you provide an example from the show?

Comment: I can do the same thing on my phone, today.

Comment: @Jörg, does this work if you never had contact with a person before and do not know yourself how to contact them?

Comment: The answer is irrelevant. This is like saying email addresses do not exist because I Can tell my secretary to send a mail to "joe". Or phone numbers do not exist because of speed dial buttons. The computer will know the person he is talking about including being able to look up addresses. You mix up the act of sending an message (technically) with an advanced voice controlled user interface that hides this fact. The OP obviously is talking about the more technical aspect.

Comment: @AlexanderKosubek: It works, if the person is in my address book, at least. Which they probably would be, since they would be in Star Fleet's address book, and my phone would be subscribed to that. I can send emails to people I have never interacted with at the companies I work for, since my phone's address book is usually synced with the company's. If I just start calling out random names, that won't work, but then again, I usually have some sort of connection with the people I want to contact, either through work, past interactions, personal, business, etc.

Comment: @TomTom my apologies for not providing specific, technical details about an interstellar communications protocol that won't be invented for several centuries, using faster than light transmissions which defy our current understanding of physics.

Comment: @AlexanderKosubek yes,I believe so. I think the advance over current systems is that it doesn't need a user specific address book, and can communicate with remote systems, or even pass the message along and allow the receiving system to figure out the final recipient. Not too different than what we have now. Although I suspect warp drive will be solved before spam.

Comment: This shows a really interesting failure of basic fundamental logic. You assume it will magically figure out where to send the mail - without even the information where the receiving system is. Magic? I mean, without kowing even which planet to send it, the only way would be to send it to EVERY recipient possible. And while that may work for "Admiral Quagaratagala Joffreysonndswads" (which on earth there may be one), try to send a message to some "John Miller". Bulk mail to possibly million of people? Magic. Sorry.

Comment: @AlexanderKosubek It works with my work directory. I don't have to know the person or email address myself for it to be able to find them, I just start typing their name and suggestions come up. And my Microsoft Exchange account is on my phone so it's linked into my contacts app so that when I go to search for contacts they come up as well as my actual contacts who I've saved manually myself.

Comment: @TomTom I never suggested it was magic. What I'm suggesting is that a natural language processing system would search for "star fleet command" first in its own data cache, then reaching out to other data sources, just like DNS does already, but more advanced. It would then pass the message to the nearest receiving server accepting messages for star fleet command. That system would then locate Admiral Nechayev, wherever she is currently assigned, and route the message there. No magic required, and except for the FTL transmission, something already within the realm of development today.

Comment: `Admiral.Nechayev@StarFleet.Command` looks like an email address.

Comment: The mechanism you describe in this answer is precisely what an email address is, and how email works. So calling it "not anything like an email address" doesn't seem quite right :P

Comment: As an email administrator myself, I can assure you that current email systems do absolutely nothing like I described. Currently email systems work by performing a DNS MX record lookup to locate the correct server, and then send it to that server. The server then determines if it accepts for that address. The intelligence I describe in locating people does not currently exist. Your email program might do a smart search of your address book, but that's it.

Answer (score 3):

There is a full (albeit high level to account for the fiction - subspace etc) breakdown of every part of the in-universe methods and operations of communication between two parties at any range. Covered includes intra-ship comms, the personal communicator, ship to ground, ship to ship, non-starfleet contacts, the subspace communications network in (fictional) detail and of course - the universal translator. Check it out, it's a good read. However, at "more pages than i care to violate copyright laws about" of mostly diagrams and their explanations, a condensed version follows.

To cover the letter writing part: The sender speaks or taps into a device (not just comm badge apparently), message is encrypted to starfleet standards / U.T. analysis, this  will usually require an id header eg "Ensign Redshirt to the bridge" or "Computer, open a channel to Ambassador Chooch on Terra Prime". Communications are routed through successive subspace relays to the recipient once the relevant network has id'ed the persons in question from previous face-to-face encounters stored in the system or analysis of intended recipient/location data. Concerning to "5 year mission" aspect: Starships regularly drop temporary subspace relays out the back while travelling to strengthen subspace signal quality in previously unknown areas of the galaxy.

References: Section 8 of the Star Trek The Next Generation Technical Manual ISBN 1-85283-340-8

Comment: Welcome to SFF.SE! To improve this answer I would suggest maybe some examples listed in the book you refer to. You don't have to copy entire pages, but can block quote text. Since you are giving proper accreditation there is no worry about copyright violations.

Comment: Also, these are priority real-time military communications over subspace, not personal letters.

Comment: @Skooba: Challenge accepted. Don't worry Valorum, I got you covered. Just cant direct at you also (limit 1). From Section 8.3 Ship-To-Ground Communications, Subsection "Applications" :

Comment: Normal Contact with the starship, if externally initiated, is divided into two basic types: Starfleet personnel, especially those directly assigned to the ship, and non-Starfleet agents. Away team members will call directly to the bridge or other active departments during the course of their work. Normal contact from outside agents will be held by Security for presentation to the captain or other senior officers. Emergency transmissions will usually be passed without computer delay for appropriate action.

Comment: There is an issue with the comments system, FYI. I suspect on my end. Continuing: Standard encryption/decryption plus enhanced security encryption protocols, are handled by FTL processors within the main computers. SF encryption algorithms are rotated / updated on random schedule. Multiple private key portions are retained within the computers, and the public key portions are transmitted to SF issue hardware vulnerable to capture by Threat forces.Calling for secure channel by either ship or remote side will place higher encrpytion levels into standby mode for confirmation by command personnel.

Answer (score 0):

Starfleet was designed to be similar to our various military organizations over the years, specifically the naval ones.  So I would assume that the process is similar to how one currently sends an email to a recipient who is actively deployed.  There is a delay and it arrives after passing the proper clearance channels/firewalls/whatever security Starfleet deems necessary.

So you would address a letter to Captain Kirk the same way that you would address one to the captain of one of the Navy's current vessels, whatever that process may be.

Comment: Out of curiosity, are deployed military today allowed to have, maintain, or use a "personal" email account? If the goal is security and safety, I'd guess not, but I'm curious if that's the case.  I don't know if they'd have an analogue to personal email accounts in the Trek era, but I suspect the rules about them would match the rules now.