# Can Voyager trace the origin of messages sent from Starfleet?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-voyager

Sort of a followup to [this](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/145313/how-do-uss-enterprise-crew-members-receive-emails-or-other-forms-of-personal-mes) question, in the Star Trek: Voyager episode [Hunters](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Hunters_(episode)), the crew uses an Hirogen network to receive messages sent from star fleet and loved ones.

With the appropriate tools I can discover where an [email came from](https://superuser.com/questions/624509/how-can-i-find-out-where-an-email-really-came-from), could Voyager trace messages (I'm aware they don't use e-mail), determine its origin, and essentially plot a course home?

Comment: They know exactly where Earth is and how to get there. It's just that it would take a really long time (>70 years).

Comment: @Loki Agreed. They were *already* plotting a course for home, but that wasn't the same thing as actually getting there any time soon.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Voyager

I think you've misunderstood slightly. Despite the crew's [repeated statements to the contrary](http://scriptsearch.dxdy.name/?page=results&query=(%7Bline%7Clost%20in%20the%20delta,%7D)), the USS Voyager isn't *lost*, they're simply very far from home. Within seconds of arriving in the Delta Quadrant (in the [pilot episode](http://www.chakoteya.net/Voyager/101.htm)) Ensign Kim uses the sensor array to accurately locate their position and identify a suitable route back to Earth.

> **KIM:** *Captain, if these sensors are working, we're over seventy thousand light years from where we were. We're on the other side of the galaxy.*

---

### The Hirogen Network

When they encounter the communications array in [VOY: Message in a Bottle](http://www.chakoteya.net/Voyager/411.htm), their first thought is to send an audio signal. It degrades quickly (for, erm, reasons) and the network bounces it back to them. Their next idea is to send a self-correcting holographic program along the network, which ends up working in both directions.

The fact that they're only sending signals would suggest that the required bandwidth to send a person (via transport) simply isn't there ***or*** that the risk of their signal degrading en-route is simply too high ***or*** that the technology simply wouldn't support it.